# How to pass object in http.send() function?

Tags: javascript, http, post, vue.js

I am trying to make a post request to a url with the following code .
Passing object to http.send(params) function gives (400) bad request error.
I am not able to trace the issue here .

```
     var http = new XMLHttpRequest()
      var url = 'http://somerandomurl'
      http.open('POST', url, true)
      http.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json')
      http.setRequestHeader('accept', 'application/json')
      http.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (http.readyState === 4 && http.status === 200) {
          returndata = http.responseText
          console.log(JSON.parse(returndata))
        }
      }
      http.send(params)
```

Solution: http.send(JSON.stringify({'email': params.email, 'password': params.password})) it worked for me .

Comment: What is the data in params? Also post the server side code. Are you able to make the request successfully with postman or rest client? If so it might be the problem with the above code otherwise it might be server side code issue.

Comment: Are you sure your `params` object is valid JSON? Your code works for me.

Comment: @KrishnadasPC it was a json complete object which was passed to this function.

Comment: @Mark_M yes it is , Caleb's solution worked for me . Thanks

Comment: Glad it worked. When you post a question post with full data. You can use dummy values but posting with complete information always helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your issue is that you are trying to send a whole object instead of JSON. The correct way to do this would be to use `http.send(JSON.stringify(params))`

Answer (score 1):

You should use one of three ways to do it
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#A_brief_introduction_to_the_submit_methods

Or either, you can take Axios.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new [fetch API](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-the-javascript-fetch-api-to-get-data) for this, makes it dead easy and less code

```
// Call the fetch function passing the url of the API as a parameter
fetch(url) 
.then(function(response) {
    // Your code for handling the data you get from the API
})
.catch(function() {
    // This is where you run code if the server returns any errors
});
```

Also if your a newbie it will get things working quicker and help you solve your problem faster.